# Language policies in education for Switzerland

Tags: language-acquisition, code-switching

In Switzerland there are 4 official languages, Italian, French, German and Romensch.

How are the education laws on the places where each one of these languages is spoken? Do the public schools enforce some kind of time proportion of language use or compulsory languages for courses?

Comment: I don't think this is about linguistics, which is the scientific study of language. It would be on topic on the [Languages.SE proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61823) though.

Comment: Many linguistics would include language policy as a branch of the study of the social aspects of language use. For example, the [Cambridge Handbook of Language Policy](http://www.cambridge.org/de/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/sociolinguistics/cambridge-handbook-language-policy) appeared in the Cambridge Handbooks in Language and Linguistics series.